# Add condition to join table in pagination query (CakePHP 2.0.4)

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I am new to cakephp. I have to do some improvements in the cakephp based application. In that, there are categories and images models. In the images table has lots of images. Default category images and other category related images details are maintaining in that table. It will display following queries in the 2nd page (pagination) of list categories.

```
SELECT `Category`.`id`, `Category`.`name`, `Category`.`slug`, `Category`.`meta_description`, `Category`.`meta_keywords`, `Category`.`sort`, `Category`.`color`, `Category`.`bgcolor`, `Category`.`modified`, `Category`.`created` FROM `categories` AS `Category`   WHERE 1 = 1   ORDER BY `sort` ASC  LIMIT 20, 20

SELECT `Image`.`id`, `Image`.`path`, `Image`.`size`, `Image`.`tags`, `Image`.`default`, `Image`.`category_id`, `Image`.`modified`, `Image`.`created` FROM `images` AS `Image` WHERE `Image`.`category_id` IN (60, 17, 9, 33, 71, 18, 73, 30, 58, 54, 3, 44, 64, 66, 67, 11, 53, 16, 23, 68)
```

But actually, the second query needs to be like:

```
SELECT `Image`.`id`, `Image`.`path`, `Image`.`size`, `Image`.`tags`, `Image`.`default`, `Image`.`category_id`, `Image`.`modified`, `Image`.`created` FROM `images` AS `Image` WHERE `Image`.`default` = 1 AND `Image`.`category_id` IN (60, 17, 9, 33, 71, 18, 73, 30, 58, 54, 3, 44, 64, 66, 67, 11, 53, 16, 23, 68)
```

There should be

> `Image`.`default` = 1
>   in WHERE clause.

My CategoriesController.php index action is:

```
public function index() {
    $this->Category->recursive = 1;
    $this->Category->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
    $this->paginate = array("contain"=>array("Image"));
    $search="";
    if(isset($this->params['named']['search'])){
        $search = str_replace("%20"," ", $this->params['named']['search']);
        $conditions = array(
            'OR' => array(
                array('Category.name LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%')
            )
        );

        $this->set('categories', $this->paginate($conditions));
    } else {
            $this->set('categories', $this->paginate());
    }
    $success = $this-> Session->read('success');
    $this->set(compact('search', 'success'));   
}
```

And my Category model has :

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Panel' => array(...),
    'Image' => array(
        'className' => 'Image',
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => array('Image.default' => '1'),
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''    
    )   
);
```

So, I need to filter the join table images.default set to '1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your categories controller change this line:

```
$this->paginate = array("contain"=>array("Image"));
```

to:

```
$this->paginate = array("contain"=>array("Image.default = 1"));
```

More info here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containing-deeper-associations

Answer (score 0):

Note: default recursive level is 1

Combine both condition into 1

```
$this->paginate = array("contain"=>array("Image.default = 1"),"recursive" => 1);
```

**or make multiple conditions**

```
$this->paginate = array('contain'=>array('Image'=>array('conditions'=>array('Image.default'=>1))))
```